# Azure Shared Website - Enable PHP in HTML

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a hosted page on Microsoft Azure Web Sites (Shared) and have verified that PHP is enabled and working but I am not able to call PHP in an .html document. Is there any way to enable this?

Searched high and low on this one, sorry if it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

This drove me nuts too, documentation in so many areas is poor. I had the same problem last week.
Here is the fix:

On the management console of the site, under configure, scroll to Handler Mappings.
In handler mappings, in the first box, type *.html 
In the second box type D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe
Save, then restart the instance. It will now process PHP inside HTML files.

One small thing, which I didn't realise till after as well. I instantly assumed, 5.5 is the latest and greatest, so why wouldn't I just update to 5.5 and use that engine. You can, and changing the folder structure to read 5.5 works, however the 5.5 build on Azure doesn't have PDO for SQL Server which makes connecting to a native SQL database a nightmare. So 5.4 is the best build IMO until they include that as well.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Not sure if this is applicable to shared, I am using a small instance, but logic should be the same I would have thought.